# Object value modified by function

Tags: solidity, hardhat, struct, string

I'm using hardhat using solidity compiler v0.8.22 in VSCode. I'm building a user database. I have a UserData struct which has a string userName. I want to allow the username to maintain case when displayed but lowercase when used as a key value so usernames are case insensitive while searching. So far it works great, I did notice though that for some reason depending on where I put my lowercase function it actually modifies the object value.

This doesn't seem to be expected behavior but maybe someone can explain better.

Here is the code for saving the userData and the output when retrieving it:

```
function _setUserData(uint256 id, UserData memory newData) internal virtual {
        
        _userData[id].indexUser = newData.indexUser;
        _userData[id].registrationDate = newData.registrationDate;
        _userData[id].defaultAddress = newData.defaultAddress;
        _userData[id].userName = newData.userName;
        _userData[id].userBio = newData.userBio;
        _userData[id].imgUrl = newData.imgUrl;
        
        for (uint256 i; i < newData.linkedProfiles.length; i++) {

            if (i >= _userData[id].linkedProfiles.length) {
                _userData[id].linkedProfiles.push(newData.linkedProfiles[i]);
            } else {
                _userData[id].linkedProfiles[i] = newData.linkedProfiles[i];
            }

        }

        _idOfName[_toLowercase(newData.userName)] = id;
        _idOfAddress[newData.defaultAddress] = id;

        emit UserDataUpdated(newData.defaultAddress, newData.userName, newData.userBio, newData.imgUrl, newData.linkedProfiles);
    }
```

Output:

```
technicallyweb3 isUser true
Result(7) [
  true,
  0n,
  '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
  'Private User',
  'This user has chosen not to index their account',
  '/assets/images/private.png',
  Result(0) []
]
```

This result is as expected, but here's what happens when I had the code in a different order, note where the _toLowercase is.

```
    function _setUserData(uint256 id, UserData memory newData) internal virtual {
        
        _idOfName[_toLowercase(newData.userName)] = id;
        _idOfAddress[newData.defaultAddress] = id;

        _userData[id].indexUser = newData.indexUser;
        _userData[id].registrationDate = newData.registrationDate;
        _userData[id].defaultAddress = newData.defaultAddress;
        _userData[id].userName = newData.userName;
        _userData[id].userBio = newData.userBio;
        _userData[id].imgUrl = newData.imgUrl;
        
        for (uint256 i; i < newData.linkedProfiles.length; i++) {

            if (i >= _userData[id].linkedProfiles.length) {
                _userData[id].linkedProfiles.push(newData.linkedProfiles[i]);
            } else {
                _userData[id].linkedProfiles[i] = newData.linkedProfiles[i];
            }

        }

        emit UserDataUpdated(newData.defaultAddress, newData.userName, newData.userBio, newData.imgUrl, newData.linkedProfiles);
    }
```

```
technicallyweb3 isUser true
Result(7) [
  true,
  0n,
  '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
  'private user',
  'This user has chosen not to index their account',
  '/assets/images/private.png',
  Result(0) []
]
```

I don't understand why the line

> _idOfName[_toLowercase(newData.userName)] = id;

causes the value of newData.userName to actually change. Is this expected behavior? Here's the _toLowercase function for reference.

```
function _toLowercase(string memory input) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory bytesInput = bytes(input);
        for (uint i = 0; i < bytesInput.length; i++) {
            // checks for valid ascii characters // will allow unicode after building a string library
            require (uint8(bytesInput[i]) > 31 && uint8(bytesInput[i]) < 127, "Only ASCII characters");
            // Uppercase character...
            if (uint8(bytesInput[i]) > 64 && uint8(bytesInput[i]) < 91) {
                // add 32 to make it lowercase
                bytesInput[i] = bytes1(uint8(bytesInput[i]) + 32);
            }
        }
        return string(bytesInput);
    }
```

Comment: Does the code in my answer below solve your problem? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The memory layout can be tricky.*

When you do `bytes memory bytesInput = bytes(input);`, you're essentially only ***shallow-copying*** the string (instantiating a `bytes` variable with bytes indexes pointing to the `input`'s memory pointers).

To make a deep copy, considering using the updated code below:

```
function copyBytes(bytes memory _bytes) private pure returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes memory copy = new bytes(_bytes.length);
        uint256 max = _bytes.length + 31;
        for (uint256 i=32; i<=max; i+=32)
        {
            assembly { mstore(add(copy, i), mload(add(_bytes, i))) }
        }
        return copy;
    }

    function _toLowercase(string memory inputNonModifiable) public pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory bytesInput = copyBytes(bytes(inputNonModifiable));

        for (uint i = 0; i < bytesInput.length; i++) {
            // checks for valid ascii characters // will allow unicode after building a string library
            require (uint8(bytesInput[i]) > 31 && uint8(bytesInput[i]) < 127, "Only ASCII characters");
            // Uppercase character...
            if (uint8(bytesInput[i]) > 64 && uint8(bytesInput[i]) < 91) {
                // add 32 to make it lowercase
                bytesInput[i] = bytes1(uint8(bytesInput[i]) + 32);
            }
        }
        return string(bytesInput);
    }
```

This is a fixed *"transform string to lower case"* version for Solidity above `^0.5.0` (that won't modify the original string in the memory).

---

A complete working example tailored to your specific logic:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Test {
    mapping(string => uint256) public _idOfName;
    mapping(address => uint256) public _idOfAddress;

    struct UserData {
        address indexUser;
        uint256 registrationDate;
        address defaultAddress;
        string userName;
        string userBio;
        string imgUrl;
        string[] linkedProfiles;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => UserData) public _userData;

    event UserDataUpdated(address defaultAddress, string userName, string userBio, string imgUrl, string[] linkedProfiles);


    /*constructor() {
        string[] memory linkedProfiles = new string[](2);

        linkedProfiles[0] = "bbbb";

        linkedProfiles[1] = "aaaa";

        UserData memory initialData = UserData({
            indexUser: address(this),
            registrationDate: block.timestamp,
            defaultAddress: address(this),
            userName: "Private User",
            userBio: "This user has chosen not to index their account",
            imgUrl: "/assets/users/incognito.jpeg",
            linkedProfiles: linkedProfiles
        });

        _userData[1] = initialData;
    }*/

        function _setUserData(uint256 id, UserData memory newData) internal virtual returns (UserData memory) {
            _idOfName[_toLowercase(newData.userName)] = id;
            _idOfAddress[newData.defaultAddress] = id;

            _userData[id].indexUser = newData.indexUser;

            _userData[id].registrationDate = newData.registrationDate;
            _userData[id].defaultAddress = newData.defaultAddress;
            _userData[id].userName = newData.userName;
            _userData[id].userBio = newData.userBio;
            _userData[id].imgUrl = newData.imgUrl;
            
            for (uint256 i; i < newData.linkedProfiles.length; i++) {
                if (i >= _userData[id].linkedProfiles.length) {
                    _userData[id].linkedProfiles.push(newData.linkedProfiles[i]);
                } else {
                    _userData[id].linkedProfiles[i] = newData.linkedProfiles[i];
                }
            }

        emit UserDataUpdated(newData.defaultAddress, newData.userName, newData.userBio, newData.imgUrl, newData.linkedProfiles);
        
        return _userData[id];
    }

    function copyBytes(bytes memory _bytes) private pure returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes memory copy = new bytes(_bytes.length);
        uint256 max = _bytes.length + 31;
        for (uint256 i=32; i<=max; i+=32)
        {
            assembly { mstore(add(copy, i), mload(add(_bytes, i))) }
        }
        return copy;
    }

    function _toLowercase(string memory inputNonModifiable) public pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory bytesInput = copyBytes(bytes(inputNonModifiable));

        for (uint i = 0; i < bytesInput.length; i++) {
            // checks for valid ascii characters // will allow unicode after building a string library
            require (uint8(bytesInput[i]) > 31 && uint8(bytesInput[i]) < 127, "Only ASCII characters");
            // Uppercase character...
            if (uint8(bytesInput[i]) > 64 && uint8(bytesInput[i]) < 91) {
                // add 32 to make it lowercase
                bytesInput[i] = bytes1(uint8(bytesInput[i]) + 32);
            }
        }
        return string(bytesInput);
    }

    function test() external returns(UserData memory) {
        string[] memory linkedProfiles = new string[](2);

        linkedProfiles[0] = "1234";

        linkedProfiles[1] = "5678";
        
        UserData memory newData = UserData({
            indexUser: address(0),
            registrationDate: block.timestamp,
            defaultAddress: address(0),
            userName: "Private User",
            userBio: "This user has chosen not to index their account",
            imgUrl: "/assets/users/incognito.jpeg",
            linkedProfiles: linkedProfiles
        });

        
        
        return _setUserData(1, newData);
    }
}
```

[image: string-bytes-shallow-deep-bytes-array-dynamic-assembly-yul-copy-solidity-to-lower-case-transform-pick]

The event log confirms that the function now works as expected, *without the extra string overwrites*:

```json
"args": {
            "0": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "1": "Private User",
            "2": "This user has chosen not to index their account",
            "3": "/assets/users/incognito.jpeg",
            "4": [
                "1234",
                "5678"
            ],
            "defaultAddress": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "userName": "Private User",
            "userBio": "This user has chosen not to index their account",
            "imgUrl": "/assets/users/incognito.jpeg",
            "linkedProfiles": [
                "1234",
                "5678"
            ]
        }
```

---

Finally, let's confirm that the key was transformed to lower case successfully:

[image: tolowercase-solidity-yul-assembly-confirmation-bug-memory-storage-deep-copy-overwrites]

Comment: AMAZING! Thanks so much for the explanation of shallow copying. I was able to reorganize my code to get it to work. My string library needed this to be a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

As Mila has answered, the value gets modified in the outer method because it is passed to the `_toLowerCase` as a memory pointer so that any modifications will affect the original value. This is how the internal calls work to optimize the performance.

I would like to add, that instead of a manual memory copy, you could save a bunch of gas, if you would handle the `UserData` as **`calldata`**. Then passing the value to `_toLowerCase` will copy the value into memory natively.

```typescript
function _setUserData(uint256 id, UserData calldata newData) internal virtual {
    _idOfName[_toLowercase(newData.userName)] = id;
    // ...
}
```

> Though it could be not always possible, as the method, which calls `_setUserData` should have the value also from the `calldata`. But if you can, it is better to go this way.

---

There is also another native way to force memory copy, but I would not suggest doing this, just to know how things work. If you use `this` keyword to call the method, then it won't be an internal call anymore, the extra `CALL` is used and therefor the value gets copied:

```typescript
function _setUserData(uint256 id, UserData memory newData) internal virtual {
    _idOfName[this._toLowercase(newData.userName)] = id;
    // ...
}
function _toLowercase(string memory input) public pure returns (string memory) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Good to know! That's a super handy and simple way to copy! What would the drawbacks be to copying with a CALL if any compared to Mila's solution? If there's no difference I could create a stringToBytes function and call bytesInput = this.stringToBytes(input) in my _toLowerCase function and fix all instances of my call

Comment: This all is about GAS usage. Calldata solution consumes far les Gas. Then comes the manuel clone. The `this` consumes the most gas, as the previous options covers everything you shouldn't use it. Go with calldata, if not possible use clone.

Comment: I think I need to stay in memory space for at least certain public calls. I need to verify the defaultAddress belongs to msg.sender and calculate and set registrationDate if they're new users. Though now that I am talking about it I'm realizing require statements could be used instead of manipulating the data, including the calculating of the user ID which was a hash of the address and timestamp as long as my dapp can get the block.timestamp and send the transaction before the next block posts. I'll need to consider if I can offload ID generation off chain and just verify. Thanks for the help!